# Is it possible to insert a pdf document inside a google doc as some sort of object?

Tags: pdf, google-docs

I have several PDF documents I am referencing in a google doc.

I would like to insert them as read-only objects in the google doc for future convinience of the readers.

Is that possible?  Unfortunately there are lots of them and I cannot take snapshot and include them as images.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display the PDF files within the docs or are you trying to perhaps reference them such as a hyperlink?

Are you trying to embed the PDf?

Try--> https://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-howtos/embed-drive-pdf